How to deal with csvs with description on top in langchain & Missing columns?
I have the following csv i want to load with langchain:

i did the following:
loader = CSVLoader(file_path='shopids.csv', encoding="utf-8",csv_args={'delimiter': ','} )

however when i looked at the output it misses the Comment column and i am unsure how to parse this csv when it has a header like above.
[
Document(page_content='\ufeff: \n: \nID: 123456\nparent org: 12', metadata={'source': 'shopids.csv', 'row': 0}), 
Document(page_content='\ufeff: \n: \nID: sallys clothes\nparent org: H&M', metadata={'source': 'shopids.csv', 'row': 1}), 
Document(page_content='\ufeff: \n: \nID: \nparent org: ', metadata={'source': 'shopids.csv', 'row': 2}), 
Document(page_content='\ufeff: \n: \nID: \nparent org: ', metadata={'source': 'shopids.csv', 'row': 3}), 
Document(page_content='\ufeff: DocID\n: Country\nID: ID\nparent org: parent org', metadata={'source': 'shopids.csv', 'row': 4}), 
Document(page_content='\ufeff: sads\n: UK\nID: 34554\nparent org: julies', metadata={'source': 'shopids.csv', 'row': 5}), 
Document(page_content='\ufeff: b. shp insurance\n: Spain\nID: 4567\nparent org: aa', metadata={'source': 'shopids.csv', 'row': 6}), 
Document(page_content='\ufeff: sads\n: Germany\nID: 34554\nparent org: julies', metadata={'source': 'shopids.csv', 'row': 7}), 
Document(page_content='\ufeff: b. shp insurance\n: USA\nID: 4567\nparent org: aa', metadata={'source': 'shopids.csv', 'row': 8}), 
Document(page_content='\ufeff: sads\n: USA\nID: 34554\nparent org: julies', metadata={'source': 'shopids.csv', 'row': 9}), 
Document(page_content='\ufeff: b. shp insurance\n: USA\nID: 924923044\nparent org: annies', metadata={'source': 'shopids.csv', 'row': 10}), 
Document(page_content='\ufeff: sads\n: USA\nID: e645605469\nparent org: hulberts', metadata={'source': 'shopids.csv', 'row': 11}), 
Document(page_content='\ufeff: b. shp insurance\n: USA\nID: 4567\nparent org: aa', metadata={'source': 'shopids.csv', 'row': 12})
]

how can i change the code such that i can include Comment column and deal with the content on first 3 lines?
unsure what ufeff is as well when i encoded it as utf-8.

ufeff is the unicode BOM (I believe). Try opening the files with encoding="utf-8-sig"

There looks to be at least be a couple of issues, essentially non-standard headers and extra descriptive lines. The BOM (\uFEFF) that you're seeing is the Byte Order Mark, which is often used to signal the encoding of UTF-8 text. It shouldn't cause problems if handled correctly. First I think you need to manually specify the header rows in order to ignore them, and using pandas or polars skip the initial descriptive lines to identify where your proper header row starts. For example, using pandas with the skiprows parameter to specify where to start reading. The BOM can then be handled automatically provided that the encoding is set to utf-8-sig:
import pandas as pds
from langchain.document_loaders import DataFrameLoader

df = pds.read_csv('shopids.csv', skiprows=3, encoding='utf-8-sig')

loader = DataFrameLoader(df)

documents = loader.load()

# Check the output
for doc in documents:
    print(doc.page_content

